# OnClick not working for button, and one other question

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert

I'm seriously struggling to get even this simple alert to work. I have to create a a very simply dynamic website where the user attempts to log in to a Dental Office's website through a form element which takes in inputs for their name, email, ID and Password. Then they check off if they want confirmation by email, and they finally choose what transaction they'd like to complete.

The assignment doesn't actually require us to use any database, and we only have to create two Javascript functions. One that validates that all the fields have been properly filled (called Validation) and one to see if that user is in the system (called Verification). Upon hitting the continue button, a simple message is displayed with your name and that you're performing whichever transaction you've completed.

For some reason, on click won't even call the simple alert function I've created, and it's incredibly frustrating. Am I using Javascript incorrectly? Also, does the rest of my code work fine for the intended purpose. Will the data entered by the user be accessible?

```js
function User(name, email, password, ID) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.password = password;
  this.ID = ID;
}

var User1 = new User(Kathy Pasos, kps @gmail.com, Pikachu2, 12345678);
var User2 = new User(Martha Pasqual, MarthaP @gmail.com, Pidgey79, 12652526);
var User3 = new User(Patrick Pavlick, pavlickP @njit.edu, Squirtl3, 13577710);
var User4 = new User(Joao Pedro, jps28 @njit.edu, Zubat21, 14308207);
var User5 = new User(Joe Perry, JAP @gmail.com, JE0000, 12696894);
var User6 = new User(Mario Costa, MCS @gmail.com, MC145, 07206143);

var Users = new Array(User1, User2, User3, User4, User5, User6);

function clickAlert() {
  alert('Hello');
}

function validation() {
  alert('Test');
  if (document.getElementById("email").includes("@") && document.getElementById("email").includes(".")) {
    Email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    return;
  } else {
    alert("That's not a valid email!");
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number">ID:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Confirmation">Receive 
        email confirmation of any transaction
            </label>
  </div><br>
  <label for="list">Select an Option:</list><br>
        <select name="Select an Option:" id="list">
            <option value="sched">Schedule an Appointment</option>
            <option value="cancel">Cancel an Appointment</option>
            <option value="search">Search for Appointment(s)</option>
            <option value="create">Create/Register an Account</option>
        </select><br>
        <br><div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="clickAlert()" 
        value="Continue">
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: String literals require delimiters.

Comment: Why is this required for such a simple alert? Every example I've seen of an onclick calling a function simply has an alert method inside the function.

Comment: `new User(Kathy Pasos,` is simply invalid syntax - like I said, strings need delimiters. It's not an issue with the `alert` or `onclick`, it's an issue with your syntax being incorrect

Comment: So, it's simply because I was an idiot and forgot to add quotation marks?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah

Comment: It works! My heart feels like it's had a weight lifted off. Thank you for pointing out my lack of caution!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick={clickAlert()} value="Continue">
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I've tried including the JS in the body, I've tried including it after the onclick, and I've even tried Jquery. Nothing seems to work. I tried waiting for the page to finish loading and then calling the function, but that doesn't work either.